# How to fast-forward a branch to a commit?

Tags: git

To put another way, how to include commit in branch *without* copying?

My situation is this:

```
* 1111111 (origin/my-branch)
* f40d3a5 (HEAD -> my-branch)
* 763dc40
* aa8d679
* 998befe
```

and I would like to include commit `1111111` into `my-branch` (see below). I know about `git cherry-pick` but that makes a copy, and I ended up with the same state as shown below after issuing `git commit --amend`...

---

#### How did this end up here?

Originally, this all looked like this,

```
* 1111111 (HEAD -> my-branch, origin/my-branch)
* f40d3a5
* 763dc40
* aa8d679
* 998befe
```

then I tried to be clever with `git commit --amend`, that resulted in

```
* 1234567 (HEAD -> my-branch)
| * 1111111 (origin/my-branch)
|/  
* f40d3a5
* 763dc40
* aa8d679
* 998befe
```

The original commit `1111111` and the resultant `1234567` are equivalent content-wise (`git diff` shows no difference), but this would have to be force-pushed... So I did

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: Can you read your first section again? It says 1234567 but the shown graph has 1111111, and you say "again, see below" which doesn't seem to refer to anything that came before in the text.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, fingers were faster than the brain...

Comment: `git merge --ff-only`

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly how a branch looks like after `fetch`ing, and the my next step is always

```
# while on `my-branch`
git rebase origin/my-branch
```

which is exactly the answer.

---

@torek's suggestion of using `git merge --ff-only` is another answer. Never heard about it before so here's the relevant section from `git help merge`:

```
--ff, --no-ff, --ff-only
  Specifies how a merge is handled when the merged-in history is already a descendant
  of the current history.  --ff is the default unless merging an annotated (and
  possibly signed) tag that is not stored in its natural place in the refs/tags/
  hierarchy, in which case --no-ff is assumed.

  With --ff, when possible resolve the merge as a fast-forward (only update the
  branch pointer to match the merged branch; do not create a merge commit). When not
  possible (when the merged-in history is not a descendant of the current history),
  create a merge commit.

  With --no-ff, create a merge commit in all cases, even when the merge could instead
  be resolved as a fast-forward.

  With --ff-only, resolve the merge as a fast-forward when possible. When not
  possible, refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status.
```

---

#### What if `1111111` was a dangling commit?

Will test this, but I presume it's

1. `git checkout 1111111` (will get into detached HEAD state)
2. `git checkout -b arbitrary-branch-name` (so that the commit won't be dangling anymore)
3. `git checkout my-branch`
4. `git rebase arbitrary-branch-name`